# Insert foreign key with other field

Tags: php, mysql

so I've try to insert data on PHP CRUD with foreign key but instead of input the number (which is the FK) I want to input an NAME

I have the following code:

```
        // Inserir os dados
    if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Dat abase::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,imei,numero_serie,ativo_sap,anexo_a,evento,data_evento,id_colaborador) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($ativo,$comentario,$data_aquisicao,$localizacao,$fabricante,$modelo,$imei,$numero_serie,$ativo_sap,$anexo_a,$evento,$data_evento,$id_colaborador));
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");
}

}
```

And I've already tried this but it won't work

```
    if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Dat abase::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,imei,numero_serie,ativo_sap,anexo_a,evento,data_evento,id_colaborador) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? (SELECT id_colaborador FROM colaboradores WHERE nome = ?))";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($ativo,$comentario,$data_aquisicao,$localizacao,$fabricante,$modelo,$imei,$numero_serie,$ativo_sap,$anexo_a,$evento,$data_evento,$id_colaborador));
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

**Note**
`id_colaborador` is the foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off passing in the ID, but if you need to use a NAME, then the format of your INSERT needs to be changed slightly (see [INSERT ... SELECT...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)) ...

```
INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,imei,
          numero_serie,ativo_sap,anexo_a,evento,data_evento,id_colaborador) 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, id_colaborador 
    FROM colaboradores 
    WHERE nome = ?
```

So the SELECT has all of the parameters as values and then it just selects the ID (id_colaborador) from the other table.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your anwser, but on that case, where do I put the VALUES ?

Comment: But even with that, it keeps giving me the same error...
`
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\tabela_superadmin\create.php:102 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\tabela_superadmin\create.php(102): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Ativos\tabela_superadmin\create.php on line 102`

Comment: I've remove 1 ? from the SELECT, try this.